# In Synergy, how can I configure a client monitor with a server monitor on either side?

Tags: multiple-monitors, synergy

I have a monitor setup where two monitors are on my Windows 10 box (server) and one monitor is used for my Mac (client). It looks like this:

```
+------+                   +------+
|      | +---------------+ |      |
|      | |               | |      |
| pc 1 | |      mac      | | pc 2 |
|      | |               | |      |
|      | |               | |      |
|      | |               | |      |
|      | +---------------+ |      |
+------+                   +------+
```

When I mouse across to the left, it goes:
Mac (leftmost) --> pc 1 --> pc 2

And the opposite to the right.

What I would like is to have the mac monitor logically in between pc 1 and pc 2. So moving the mouse all the way to the left would be pc 1, moving right would be mac, and then all the way on the right would be pc 2.

But since both of the monitors are hooked up to the same system, I can't separate them in the config.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I want to have similar setup eventaully, but, at the moment, I 'm unable even to configure your current setup (i.e.: mac client screen in the middle of two PC server screens). Could you please tell me how to do so .. Thank you

Comment: I just have that set up by physically plugging in the two devices (PC and Mac) into the center monitor and switching the input source on the monitor itself to switch between PC and Mac.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality won't be available in an intuitive way until per-monitor configuration with uneven edges hits in Synergy 2.1 (2.0 is still in beta at time of writing).

You should be able to fake this though, as long as you're okay with the PC screens 'wrapping' around.

For your specific use case, put PC screen 1 to the right of PC screen 2 in Windows display settings and then set up synergy to wrap around (PC is to both the left and right of Mac).

Comment: "... and then set up synergy to wrap around (PC is to both the left and right of Mac)." how to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question.

However, if there isnt a fix, Ill explain what I did and hopefully OP might find it useful.

I just placed the vertical screens  beneath center screen (both PC for me but the idea works).  The other thing I found handy was making a hot key that locked my mouse to the current device, so when I locked it to the 2 vertical screens, I can still switch between the two and lock myself out of the center screen, a powerful feature for my gaming/streaming purpose.

Would still be interested in a the option OP is asking about for other uses.